# Map Values and Replace

Tags: r

I have two dataframes like so:

Nodes:

```
new_id  Name  old_id
1        foo    560
2        fie    561
3        fee    562
4        fim    563
```

Rels:

```
StartID   EndID
560       561
561       563
561       562
563       560
```

Where the IDs in the second file are the old IDs in the first. I want to update the IDs in the second files based on matching row in the first.

Desired end:

```
StartID  EndID
1         2
2         4
2         3
4         1
```

I was looking at `replace()`, but it's unclear how I would be able to use this without knowing the indices.

Comment: check the *?match* function.

Comment: What is your expected output?It's not clearer to me what you want at the end?

Comment: I couldn't  understand either.

Comment: Is this better? I am looking up match now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vector that maps `old_id` to `new_id`

```
(map <- setNames(nodes$new_id, nodes$old_id))
#560 561 562 563 
#  1   2   3   4
```

and one way to use it is the following

```
apply(rels, 2, function(x) map[as.character(x)])
#     StartID EndID
#[1,]       1     2
#[2,]       2     4
#[3,]       2     3
#[4,]       4     1
```

Comment: This makes a ton of sense. Thank you!

Comment: This finally finished and I got all NAs as the result. I'm still trying to figure out why.

Comment: @OlgaMu, there must be something different than in your example. Do you still have data frames of such structure?

Answer (score 3):

the `match` function (returning an index into new_id) was what you were looking for:

```
cbind(StartID = Nodes$new_id[match( Rels$StartID ,Nodes$old_id)] , 
      EndID = Nodes$new_id[match( Rels$EndID ,Nodes$old_id)] )

     StartID EndID
[1,]       1     2
[2,]       2     4
[3,]       2     3
[4,]       4     1
```

Comment: until now I assumed match and %in% were synonyms. +1 for opening my eyes.

Comment: `%in%` is a particular application of `match`, but `match` returns a numerical vector rather than a logical vector. They may both be useful for constructing lookup-index-vectors.

Comment: Since `%in%` doesn't give the position of the match, how could it be useful for that task?

Comment: It returns a logical vector of the same length as the first argument, so it can be used in some situations with "[" as an index.